# Error: Two main PROGRAMs in an f77 Program

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I read a paper that has f77 fortran code. I want to run the program and step through it so I can port it over to MATLAB. However, when I try to run the program, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
$f77 -g Algorithm634.f 
Algorithm634.f:10.72:

      INTEGER FITDEG,DIMEN,NFPOLS,NFPTS,NEPTS,NEPOLS,EVLDEG,TOPS        
                                                                        1
Algorithm634.f:142.72:

      INTEGER DIMEN,FITDEG,NFPOLS,NFPTS,EVLDEG,NEPOLS,NEPTS             
                                                                        2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)
```

Clearly, I need to refactor the code. (1) listed above generates data that is then used in (2). However, I am not familiar with old f77 programs. I am not sure exactly what to do to refactor this.

[Dropbox Fortran file and Papers](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xys9mvy43ct9419/AADXHR8TTpxMKIZtJhf3-6xta?dl=0)

EDIT:
I was told not to link to dropbox. Fine. Here is the whole program:

https://pastebin.com/ULLLPmdL

Comment: Please show us the actual code. The error message is pretty straightforward and sure has been discussed before. Do not link to Dropbox, cut and paste a [mcve] here.

Comment: Try looking here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Two+main+PROGRAMs+at+(1)+and+(2)+site:stackoverflow.com You will see threre are multiple possible problems and we cannot say which one is yours without your code.

Comment: 1. The program is 1600 lines. Why should I paste it here rather than link to it on my dropbox? I am not a fortran programmer. I just need to get this working well enough to step through it. I don't care to learn fortran either. I just need the bare minimum.

Comment: 2. Your google search is for f90. I am working in f77. The layout is different and doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: 3. I don't even know how to write a proper "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" in f77. If I did, I definitely wouldn't be posting here because I would just fix it. I am looking to save some time by getting some quick help and then focus on porting this to MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded Algorithm634.f from your dropbox.
As the compiler message suggests, there are 2 separate programs, which I created as generate.for and driver.for.

If you compile and link them as generate.exe and driver.exe, you can then run them.

First the generate program, as:

```
gFortran generate.for -o generate.exe
generate > generate.txt
```

this will produce the data file that is required for driver.

Then use the driver program, as:

```
gFortran driver.for -o driver.exe
driver < generate.txt > driver.txt
```

This will produce some output, which you can review.

( Actually, I changed generate.for, by including the first executable line as:

```
  open (unit=16, file='gendat.txt')
```

then changed all `write (6,` to `write (16,` so that the output was written to a file, rather than redirected.

I then changed driver.for, by including the first executable line as:

```
  open (unit=15, file='gendat.txt')
```

then changed all `read (5,` to `read (15,` so that the input was read from a file, rather than redirected.

Changing units 5,6 to 15,16 is to avoid potential problems with reserved file unit numbers in the range 1:9, which different Fortran compilers can apply. )

I would leave it to you to confirm the program works.
Most Fortran compilers have an associated "debugger" which will allow you to step through the program, so you may complete your next phase.

code.f or code.for indicates the code layout is fixed format code. As well as F77 compilers, all F90+ Fortran compilers will recognise this code and should cope.

In summary, the solution is to separate Algorithm634.f into the 2 separate files.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. I don't have time at exactly this moment. though.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you!!!! 

I was using tdm-gcc-5.1.0-3. Apparently, the read command for existing files does not work. Ugh!!!! I kept getting segmentation faults! Ugh. I switched to a newer version, 5.3, from another developer and it worked.

Comment: FYI, the bug for tdm-gcc.5.1 is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/487/